# Fancybox, button feature is not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to use the extended button functionality for fancybox. But as i add this JS into the code it does not work. The example link is http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ under "Extended functionality" paragraph. The given code for adding extended button does not function:

```
helpers     : {
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    }
```

What's problem or smth. missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that i didn't include the helpers for extended button (as well as for thumbs) functionality .js and .css from helpers folder. As i've included, it worked perfect:

```
/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js 
/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css
```